# Append a list on a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary where values are a list of lists:

```
for line in scenariofile:
    if re.match('^pppoe|^dhcp|^static|^sfu|^hgu', line):
        line = line.rsplit()
        print(line) # Just for debug
        scenariolist.update({line[0]: [].append(line)})

print(scenariolist)
```

This is the output:

```
['pppoe', '1001', 'jon', 'jon123']
['pppoe', '2000', 'joe', 'joe123']
['dhcp', '1001']
['dhcp', '1000']
['static', '1010', '192.168.2.40', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.2.1', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']
['sfu', '1001', 'untagged']
['hgu', '1001']

{'pppoe': None, 'dhcp': None, 'static': None, 'sfu': None, 'hgu': None}
```

So, the lines have content, but I don't know why they are not appended on as values on the list.

I expected some output like this:

```
{'pppoe': [['pppoe', '1001', 'jon', 'jon123'], ['pppoe', '2000', 'joe', 'joe123']]... and so on
```

Comment: `append()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not appending to the list that's in the dictionary. `[].append(line)` creates a temporary list, appends to it, and then returns `None`, and this `None` value is put into the dictionary.

You can use a `collections.defaultdict` for this, to create a dictionary element that contains a list as needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

scenariolist = defaultdict(list)
for line in scenariofile:
    if re.match('^pppoe|^dhcp|^static|^sfu|^hgu', line):
        line = line.rsplit()
        print(line) # Just for debug
        scenariolist[line[0]].append(line)

print(scenariolist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
for line in scenariofile:
    if re.match('^pppoe|^dhcp|^static|^sfu|^hgu', line):
        line = line.rsplit()
        print(line) # Just for debug
        if line[0] in scenariolist:
            scenariolist[line[0]].append(line)
        else:
            scenariolist.update({line[0]: [line]})
    

print(scenariolist)
```